# Knowing how my Ubuntu is installed

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside windows 7 using a USB stick and universal Ubuntu installer. I now want to know whether my disk has been partitioned, or whether Ubuntu is installed within Windows... and also how I should uninstall Ubuntu 13.04 if I want to.

When I give the `df-h` command the following is the o/p

> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/sda6       7.2G  3.0G  3.9G  44% /
>
> none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
>
> udev            1.4G  4.0K  1.4G   1% /dev
>
> tmpfs           287M  820K  286M   1% /run
>
> none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
>
> none            1.4G  152K  1.4G   1% /run/shm
>
> none            100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
>
> /dev/sda5       142G  1.8G  140G   2% /media/zakirhussain/DATA
>
> /dev/sda2       122G   70G   53G  57% /media/zakirhussain/OS

Answer (score 0):

If `df` it's not enough, you can try [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/).

You may want to see also:

- [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)